# Can get entries but not gravity

Tags: java, android

I wrote my spinner based on `AppCompatSpinner`.

I want to get entries and gravity. Here is my code:

```
public class RxSpinner extends AppCompatSpinner {

private static final int[] RX_SPINNER_OVERRIDE_ATTRS = {
        android.R.attr.entries,
        android.R.attr.gravity
};

public RxSpinner(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RxSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RxSpinner);
    final int textColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.RxSpinner_text_color, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_dark));
    final int dropdownTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.RxSpinner_dropdown_text_color, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_dark));
    final float textSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.RxSpinner_text_size, context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_normal));
    a.recycle();

    a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,RX_SPINNER_OVERRIDE_ATTRS);
    if (a.hasValue(0)){
        CharSequence[] entries = a.getTextArray(0);
        final int gravity = a.getInt(1, Gravity.CENTER);    // here is the problem  always default value.
        //create adapter
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(context, R.layout.item_spinner_top, R.id.text, entries) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView text = ButterKnife.findById(view, R.id.text);
                text.setTextColor(textColor);
                text.setTextSize(DimenUtils.px2dp(textSize));
                text.setGravity(gravity);
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View dropDownView = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView text = ButterKnife.findById(dropDownView, R.id.text);
                text.setTextColor(dropdownTextColor);
                text.setTextSize(DimenUtils.px2dp(textSize));
                text.setGravity(gravity);
                return dropDownView;
            }
        };
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.item_spinner_dropdown);
        setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    a.recycle();

    //set background tint
    ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(this, ColorStateList.valueOf(textColor));
}
}
```

I can only get entries but not gravity.

It seems the same mode, can anybody tell me why?

I know there is other way to get gravity, but I am more interested in the reason.

Comment: sure no problem. Just try to write "I" uppercase and leave a space after commas -> (..., ...) , i am German by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the reason myself.
It is overwritten in appcompat-v7 package.

```
<declare-styleable name="Spinner"><attr format="reference" name="prompt"/><attr format="enum" name="spinnerMode"><enum name="dialog" value="0"/><enum name="dropdown" value="1"/></attr><attr name="android:dropDownSelector"/><attr name="android:popupBackground"/><attr name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset"/><attr name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset"/><attr name="android:dropDownWidth"/><attr format="reference" name="popupPromptView"/><attr name="android:gravity"/><attr format="boolean" name="disableChildrenWhenDisabled"/><attr name="android:background"/></declare-styleable>
```

so you can get the value in this way:

```
    a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.Spinner);
    final int gravity = a.getInt(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.Spinner_android_gravity,Gravity.CENTER);
    a.recycle();
```